# Expected length of a random human being is the same as average of the complete human population

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $n$ be the number of people in the world. And let $X_i$ be the corresponding length in centimeter. I'm trying to prove that $1/n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=EX_1$.

\begin{align}
EX_1 &= \sum_{x=0}^{251} x P(X_1=x) \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{251} x \frac{\#\{X_i:X_i = x\}}{n} \\
&=1/n \sum_{x=0}^{251} x \#\{X_i:X_i = x\} \\ 
&=1/n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\end{align}

That this last equality is true, is quite obvious, if you are going to think about it. But I find it rather hard to proof. Any ideas ?

Comment: maybe induction....?

Comment: If the height of each person is independent and identically distributed, or at least each $X_i$ has the same expected value, then you can prove it.  Otherwise you can't.

Comment: Why do you have 251, 250, etc. above?

Comment: it should be only 251, I edit it. $\{0,1,...,251\}$ are the different lengths a person can have (in cm).

Comment: What is the sample space here? If $X_i$ is the height of person $i$, then why would person $1$ be exactly the average height of the ensemble? If the sample space is $\{1,...,n\}$ then $E X_1$ makes no sense (or rather $E X_1 = X_1$ so what would the point be?). I think the problem is badly posed.

Comment: I would say that the last line follows from the preceding line using the fact that, for any natural number $k$, $xk$ equals the sum of $k$ copies of $x$, combined with the commutativity of addition.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say this is hard to prove.  Much more problematic, from my point of view, is line 2.  You need to assume something about how people in the world are associated with the subscripts $i$.  One assumption that would work is that people are chosen one-by-one, at random, and without replacement, and that $X_i$ represents the height of the $i^\text{th}$ person chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the $X_i$ satisfy $E X_i = E X_1$.

Then, by linearity of expectation, $E (\frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i E X_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i E X_1 = E X_1$.

**Addendum**: I think the problem is badly worded. I think the sample space is $\Omega = \{1,...,n\}$ and the distribution uniform, that is $p \{ i\} = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $i \in \Omega$.

I think the statement should be to show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i = E X$, in which case it really just reduces to the definition, which is
$E X = \int_\Omega X dp = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ p \{ i\} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i$.

Comment: Did this prove the statement ? Or do you mean that: $1/n \sum_i X_i = E(1/n \sum_i X_i)$?

Comment: Well, you need to be a little careful. What do you mean by $E X_1$? Is $X_1$ the height of a specific person?

Comment: In the exercise, it states: 
>Choose one person of the $n$ persons in this world. And denote his or her length as $X_1$.

Comment: I am confused by the problem. Why would be average height be the height of the person corresponding to $X_1$?